# I don't understand why my output changed, please help me

Tags: arrays, quicksort, freepascal

I'm using Free Pascal to build a function to sort an array of integers called QuickSort, which uses the quicksort algorithm.
Here is my program:

```
uses crt;
var
        i,n : integer;
        A : array[1..100] of integer;

procedure QuickSort(var arr : array of integer; l,r : integer);
var
        i,j,y,x : integer;

begin
        i := l; j := r;
        x := arr[(l+r) div 2];
        repeat
                while arr[i] < x do inc(i);
                while x < arr[j] do dec(j);
                if i <= j then
                begin
                        y := arr[i]; arr[i] := arr[j]; arr[j] := y;
                        inc(i); dec(j);
                end;
        until i > j;
        if l < j then QuickSort(arr,l,j);
        if i < r then QuickSort(arr,i,r);
end;

BEGIN
        readln(n);
        for i := 1 to n do
        begin
                write('A[',i,'] = ');
                readln(A[i]);
        end;
        QuickSort(A,1,n);
        for i := 1 to n do write(A[i]:7);
        readln;
END.
```

Whatever my input is, it doesn't work. But when I change this

```
var
        i,n : integer;
        A : array[1..100] of integer;

procedure QuickSort(var arr : array of integer; l,r : integer);
```

into this

```
type
        Array_ = array[1..100] of integer;
var
        i,n : integer;
        A : Array_;

procedure QuickSort(var arr : Array_; l,r : integer);
```

it works perfectly. Can someone explain it to me? Thank you :))

Comment: I wonder what "additional details" the close voter is missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the function as

```
procedure QuickSort(var arr : array of integer; l,r : integer);
```

you declare the array as an "Open array parameter" and some special rules apply. An "Open array parameter" allows different sized arrays to be passed to the function. However, for this to work correctly some rules must be followed, of which you did not follow this one:

> Within the body of a routine, the indexing starts with 0 (regardless of how the passed in array was defined). You can use `Low` and `High` to learn the index range, which also can be expressed as 0..Length-1.